# Override dependency property value

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I would like to know the best way on intercepting a DP value and scale it by a certain factor in a way as XAML friendly as possible, without subclassing the control. Just to explain better, I'm working on a behavior that manages zoom on canvas ( and derived ) objects, and I want being easy to "unscale" certain DP ( for example line thickness ) by the current scale factor, so I would like some XAML friendly way to let the user specify which property unscale, and let me intercept to apply the proper scaling factor, that I know as the agent who is providing the zoom. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you leveraging the MultiScaleImage code that exists already for WPF http://blogs.windowsclient.net/joeyw/archive/2008/08/05/pan-and-zoom-deepzoom-style-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: Hmm...the blogger is on twitter; may be able to contact him as the src, etc...may exist elsewhere now....@woodjoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata.aspx) to do the job I need.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to achieve is constant-width strokes when zooming in/out try zooming using transform on your Geometry objects instead of on your Visual/FrameworkElement objects.

Good luck!

Comment: You mean apply the scale trasform to all the objects in the scene ?

Comment: I mean apply the scale transform only to the Geometry of objects in the scene. For example, if you have a Path, then it has a geometry in its Path.Data. Every geometry has a Transform property. You can bind this transform to your scaling factor when creating the geometries and the zoom will happen.

Comment: Well, zoom is a view trasform, I would prefer apply the trasform to the "view" ( the canvas ) instead of trasforming the objects, even if I want to display the runnign coordinate of a cursor, is betetr to have the canvas scaled.